# Restrictions.Disjunction().Add(Subqueries.WhereValue(1)

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

What does this mean in nhibernate. Can anyone give me a small example?Can someone give me an example of

```
Restrictions.Disjunction().Add(Subqueries.WhereValue(1).Eq(subquerycount)..
```

What do these @p3, @p7 do?

```sql
select  a1, a2 from table1
inner join table2
where (
@p3 = (select count(somevariable)
from t1)
or
table2.isspecific = 0
and @p7=(Select count...)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming `subquerycount` is a detached Criteria or QueryOver. With that in mind:

```
Restrictions.Disjunction()
```

- The `Restrictions` class is a helper class for building... well, restrictions. These are translated by NHibernate into the `WHERE` portion of the SQL query that's ultimately generated.
- The `Disjunction` method is a helper method that creates a *disjunction*. In this context, that's an arbitrary number of conditions joined together with `OR`. There's also `Restrictions.Conjunction()` which generates a *conjunction*, which is the same thing except joined together with `AND`.

This is what's creating the SQL in the `WHERE` clause that you posted. Specifically the `OR` part:

```sql
(
@p3 = (select count(somevariable)
from t1)
or -- Right here
table2.isspecific = 0
and @p7=(Select count...)
)
```

The next portion:

```
.Add(Subqueries.WhereValue(1).Eq(subquerycount)
```

We're saying "Take this disjunction and add a condition to it". We're basically adding an expression that will be `OR`'d with other expressions (if any).

The expression we're adding (`Subqueries.WhereValue(1).Eq(subquerycount)`) is (probably) equal to this bit in the SQL:

```
@p3 = (select count(somevariable)
from t1)
```

Hopefully that helps explain what the line in question was doing.

> What do these @p3, @p7 do?

NHibernate generates [parameterized SQL](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). When you supply a value (like "1" in your example), that gets sent to the database in the form of a parameter. The `@p0 ... @pn` values you see in the generated SQL are just parameters that are auto-generated by NHibernate for you.

In your example, I'm guessing `@p3` gets assigned to `1`.